# Grails starting with a database error has anyone seen this

Tags: grails, ddl

I started my application today and when it starts I get this error

> | Error 2012-09-14 13:54:17,608 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table order (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, date_created timestamp not null, order varchar(255) not null, picture_id bigint not null, posts_id bigint not null, primary key (id))
>
> | Error 2012-09-14 13:54:17,609 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ORDER[*] (ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL, DATE_CREATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PICTURE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, POSTS_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
>   create table order (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, date_created timestamp not null, order varchar(255) not null, picture_id bigint not null, posts_id bigint not null, primary key (id)) [42001-164]
>
> | Error 2012-09-14 13:54:17,621 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: alter table order add constraint FK651874E9A8021F6 foreign key (posts_id) references post
>
> | Error 2012-09-14 13:54:17,621 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE ORDER[*] ADD CONSTRAINT FK651874E9A8021F6 FOREIGN KEY (POSTS_ID) REFERENCES POST "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
>   alter table order add constraint FK651874E9A8021F6 foreign key (posts_id) references post [42001-164]
>
> | Error 2012-09-14 13:54:17,621 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: alter table order add constraint FK651874ED45FCA4B foreign key (picture_id) references picture
>
> | Error 2012-09-14 13:54:17,621 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE ORDER[*] ADD CONSTRAINT FK651874ED45FCA4B FOREIGN KEY (PICTURE_ID) REFERENCES PICTURE "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
>   alter table order add constraint FK651874ED45FCA4B foreign key (picture_id) references picture [42001-164]

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Post the domain class Order, please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are some keys are not allowed in GORM: order, group or any other SQL keyword; also you can't name domain class User, Group(PostgreSQL).
To fix it read [mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapping.html) and change table names and columns.

Answer (score 6):

I have found out you cannot have field or domain with the name: order, group or any other SQL keyword.